# alert() in focusin event continues popping up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click inside the `<input>` tag below, the `alert()` in the following code keeps appearing after I click the "OK" button of the `alert()`.

What I need to do to stop the alert after clicking the "OK" button? My code needs to get out of the input tag and do some other things.

```
....
<input type="text" class="txtInput" value="Test for focusin event" />
....
<input type="button" id="goBtn" value="GO" />
<script>
$(".txtInput").focusin(function () {
    var t = $(this).val();
    alert(t);
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a boolean flag track if you have already focused:

```
    ....
<input type="text" class="txtInput" value="Test for focusin event" />
....
<input type="button" id="goBtn" value="GO" />
<script>
var focused=false;
$(".txtInput").focusin(function () {
    if(focused) return;
    focused=true;
    var t = $(this).val();
    alert(t);
});
<script>
```

After execution you can set the value back to false.

Alternately, you can unbind the handler and rebind it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when the input gets focused, the alert pops up, and then the input loses the focus. When you close the alert box, the focus goes back to whatever it was before (the input), so the input gets the focus, and the alert pops up, ...

Just get rid of it. If you want to debug use [**`console.log`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log).

Answer (score 0):

Focus returns to the `input` after the `alert()` dialog closes. If you want to make sure you only `alert()` once, keep track:

```
var alerted = false;

$(".txtInput").focusin(function () {

  if (! alerted) {
    alerted = true;

    var t = $(this).val();

    alert(t);
  }
});
```

or just use `console.log()` instead, and avoid `alert()` popups and multiple-focus issues altogether.

```
$(".txtInput").focusin(function () {
  var t = $(this).val();
  console.log(t);
});
```